# How to make Rider code autoformating to make 2 spaces indent instead of 4 in .csproj files?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

I tried root `.editorconfig`:

```
[*.csproj]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
```

I tried internal settings:

[image]

Nothing worked for me. I need a very simple thing: When I press `ctrl` + `alt` + `l` (autoformat in my key map) I want to see 2 spaces in `.csproj` files. Rider makes 4.

Comment: Not answering your issue (not a Rider user) but just to clarify: do you want this indent for the code ... or "XML documentation" (this is what you have selected on your screenshot). Because .editorconfig's `indent_size` will not work for Docs indents, only for general indents (i.e. the space before `///`)

Comment: I want autoformatting to make me 2 spaces in .csproj file instead of 4. .csproj is some kind of XML file (not XML documentation).

Comment: What do you see in the Status Bar for the indents? If you click on that Indents widget there, what kind of menu will you see? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Guided_Tour_Around_the_User_Interface.html#status-bar It should show what options it uses.

Comment: Is EditorConfig actually enabled for this project? Maybe it ignores that file / another config file is used? Anyway: please check the following link if you have not used it yet: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Using_EditorConfig.html#in_solution , the _"In the Code Style Configuration dialog, you can see and study all .editorconfig files that affect the current file:"_ part / screenshot in particular -- does it give you any hints?

Comment: BTW -- *"`.csproj` is some kind of XML file"* if it's XML file, then try also checking XML Code Style and not just C# -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Settings_Code_Style_XML.html

Answer (score 2):

The `.editorconfig` settings seem to be ignored for csproj files. I was able to get it working by changing Tabs and Indents within Editor => Code Style => XML.

[image]